# Does the SparkSQL Dataframe function explode preserve order?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Scala spark DataFrame:

```
df.select($"row_id", $"array_of_data").show
+----------+--------------------+
| row_id   |      array_of_data |
+----------+--------------------+
|       0  | [123, ABC, G12]    |
|       1  | [100, 410]         |
|       2  | [500, 300,  ...]   |
```

I want to explode those arrays so that each element is in a different row, but I also want to mark which row corresponds to the first element of the array:

```
+----------+--------------------+----------+----------+
| row_id   |      array_of_data | exploded | is_first |
+----------+--------------------+----------+----------+
|       0  | [123, ABC, G12]    | 123      |    Yes   |
|       0  | [123, ABC, G12]    | ABC      |    No    |
|       0  | [123, ABC, G12]    | G12      |    No    |
```

To achieve this, I use the [explode function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$), and hope that the first row corresponds to the first data element:

```
var exploded_df = df.withColumn("exploded", explode($"array_of_data"))

val window = Window.partitionBy("row_id").orderBy("row_id")
// Create an internal rank variable to figure out the first element
exploded_df = exploded_df.withColumn("_rank", row_number().over(window))
exploded_df = exploded_df.withColumn("is_first",
                                     when(($"_rank" === 1), "Yes").otherwise("No")
                                    )
```

This appears to work for my purposes and produces the desired output, but can I trust that this will always work? I can't find anywhere in the explode documentation that promises this behavior, and it seems unwise to trust the order of rows in a Spark dataframe.

The only other solution I could think of would be to create a new column for every element in `array_of_data` and then match when `exploded` is equal to the value from the first column, but I don't have a guarantee that there wont be duplicate values in the array.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [posexplode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#posexplode-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) function for that purpose.

As the api document explains it

> > Creates a new row for each element with position in the given array or map column.

You can use `select` function so that the *position* and *exploded column* form separate columns as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.select($"row_id", posexplode($"array_of_data")).show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+------+---------------+---+---+
|row_id|array_of_data  |pos|col|
+------+---------------+---+---+
|0     |[123, ABC, G12]|0  |123|
|0     |[123, ABC, G12]|1  |ABC|
|0     |[123, ABC, G12]|2  |G12|
+------+---------------+---+---+
```